# Group column based on value into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to generate a new column that will show groups of the data in a different column in my df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,10,100, 15,23,18, 3000, 2, 500]})
```

I would like to create a new column that will group them into 3 groups based on the values of a:
"high" (<5), "medium"(5-15), "low", (>15).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `np.select` or `pd.cut`

```py
df['col'] = np.select([df['a']<5, df['a'].between(5,15), df['a']>15], ['high', 'medium', 'low'])

# or

df['col1'] = pd.cut(df['a'], [-np.inf, 5, 15, np.inf], labels=['high', 'medium', 'low'])
```

```
print(df)

      a     col    col1
0     1    high    high
1    10  medium  medium
2   100     low     low
3    15  medium  medium
4    23     low     low
5    18     low     low
6  3000     low     low
7     2    high    high
8   500     low     low
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried both options but got the following error:
<ipython-input-22-f988391e38e7>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @RanAntes You seem use part of the dataframe not the original one.

Comment: Thanks @Ynjxsjmh. Not sure what you mean... sorry